# Why does code folding HTML in Sublime break with my <textarea>?

Tags: html, sublimetext3, sublimetext, code-folding

I have the following in an HTML file opened in Sublime:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>code folding bug</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <textarea>I am the very model of a modern Major-General,
I've information vegetable, animal, and mineral,
I know the kings of England, and I quote the fights historical.</textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: code folding bug in Sublime]

Notice, it shows that I can collapse (with the ▼ on the left) only the `<head>` and `<body>` elements (not the `<div>` or `<textarea>`).

If I collapse the `<body>` element it get's weirder with only the first two lines inside the element disappearing:

[image]

I am using Sublime Text 3 (build 3126) on Windows 10 x64 with Package Manager being the only package installed.

Comment: The code folding works fine for me in Dreamweaver, so I can only assume it's a bug in Sublime.

Comment: I just tried it and was able to reproduce it in Sublime so it looks like it might be a bug. BTW, it folded correctly when I put all the tags and text on new lines and indented the text past the textarea tag. So maybe this is actually by design.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Thanks. Yes, if I put the text at the same level as the opening `<textarea>` tag, the div and body elements will fold correctly. That would be a terrible design choice to only fold the first two lines. Try placing a bunch of paragraphs right after the textarea. It gets worse with more lines.

Comment: Try to add some css classes to your div and textarea.

Comment: @AHBagheri Tried that. No change.